# What the difference (in construction) between a tcolorbox with width=\linewidth key and without it

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, paragraphs, right-to-left, bidi

I have this example of two tcolorbox in RTL context (lualatex) both are preceded with `\textdir TLT`, the first tcolorbox has the option `width=\linewidth` and the second one does not have this option, textdir inside the first tcolorbox is TLT but inside the second textdir change to TRT

I thought the way the two tcolorbox are built is the same but it turns out to be different which causes this difference to appear

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT \bodydir TRT \textdir TRT

\noindent 
{\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth] 
Text 
\the\textdir
\end{tcolorbox}}

\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}
text
\the\textdir
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the difference that in the first case `\textdir` is in horizontal mode, as it follows `\noindent` but in the second case it is in vertical mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The difference is unrelated to the width option.  In the first case you have `\textdir` within the line, in horizontal mode. In the second you are issuing it in in vertical mode,

Adding `\noindent` to the second case produces the result above.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT \bodydir TRT \textdir TRT

\noindent 
{\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth] 
Text 
\the\textdir
\end{tcolorbox}}

\noindent
\textdir TLT\begin{tcolorbox}
text
\the\textdir
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So `\textdir TLT` in vertical mode has no effect on text direction ?

Comment: @SalimBou ah, I was hoping you wouldn't ask:-) the details of how these all interact is complicated and more or less completely undocumented in the luatex manual. Some years back I did try to write down a list of the combinations as I understood it at the time, I'll see if I can find a link.

Comment: Without `\textdir TLT`   before tcolorbox the box go in opposite direction!!!