# Commands \textdir TLT and \pardir TLT strange effect with \bodydir TRT if inserted before \setbox (vertical mode)

Tags: luatex, boxes, right-to-left

This is a complement of my previous question [What the difference (in construction) between a tcolorbox with width=\linewidth key and without it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615369/what-the-difference-in-construction-between-a-tcolorbox-with-width-linewidth), I noticed that the issue appear if we add \textdir TLT or \pardir TLT before `\setbox` in vertical mode text inside box still in TRT direction unlike  if we insert the two commands in horizontal mode

Is this a normal effect of primitives  `\bodydir`, `\textdir` and `\pardir` or a luatex bug?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newbox\mybox
\parindent=0pt
    
\begin{document}
    
\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT \bodydir TRT % with \bodydir TLT issue do not appear
    
{\textdir TLT  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{t:\the\textdir - p:\the\pardir - b:\the\bodydir} 
\box\mybox} 
    
\leavevmode% 
{\textdir TLT \setbox\mybox=\hbox{t:\the\textdir - p:\the\pardir - b:\the\bodydir} 
\box\mybox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are investigating?

Comment: @Cicada textdir and pardir in the two boxes should be TLT but in the first box they are TRT

Answer (score 1):

A proper answer will hopefully be given by those who know much about such things, but part of the answer has to do with *when* the command takes effect, e.g. after the current paragraph has completed, not during the paragraph.

Doing a `\textdir TLT \pardir TLT\par\`  instead of `\textdir TLT \pardir TLT` allows the following box to pick up those new directions.

[image: vertical and horizontal]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\newbox\mybox
%\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
All TRT:

\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT  \textdir TRT \bodydir TRT

\textdir TLT \pardir TLT \setbox\mybox=\hbox{First: t:\the\textdir; p:\the\pardir; b:\the\bodydir.} \box\mybox 

\ %<== Typeset a space = leave vertical mode 
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{Second:  t:\the\textdir; p:\the\pardir; b:\the\bodydir.} \box\mybox

\bigskip
All TRT, + mode switch after settings;

\pagedir TRT \pardir TRT  \textdir TRT \bodydir TRT

\textdir TLT \pardir TLT\par\  \setbox\mybox=\hbox{First: t:\the\textdir; p:\the\pardir; b:\the\bodydir.} \box\mybox 


\end{document}
```

Note that, of all the possible theoretical combinations of directions and elements (32, I think) in Omega, only real-world combinations (8?) were ported over into LuaTex, so expect some potential anomalies if you want to try out the others.

Comment: With `\par\ ` we enter in horizontal mode same with  second case using  leavevmode

Comment: Yes. If the comment is a question: The paragraph commands (eg., pardir) take effect when: in the middle of a paragraph box, or on the next paragraph box? Looks like next. Correct? Just a guess. Any examples to the contrary?